# How to add 2 animations to one html tag using animate.css?

Tags: css, jquery-animate, animate.css

I want to add 2 different types of animations to one of my HTML objects using Animate.css by Dane Den. https://github.com/daneden/animate.css

Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use css instead of classes to do this.
If you use classes the last will overwrite the other classes.

```
animation-name: animation1, animation2, animation3;
```

For example:

If you would like to use `bounce`, `flash` and `pulse`, you can write your own class to do that:

**HTML**

```
<div class="animated myAnimations"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.myAnimations {
    animation-name: bounce, flash, pulse;
    -webkit-animation-name: bounce, flash, pulse;



    /*
    you can set different proporties to different animations too:
    1s to bounce
    2s to flash
    3s to pulse
    */

    animation-duration: 1s, 2s, 3s;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s, 2s, 3s;
}
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/nn18co76/1/)

Comment: Could you give me an example please?

Comment: Sorry I left the `animated` class.

Comment: .myAnimation {
    animation-name: zoomIn, zoomOutDown;
    -webkit-animation-name: zoomIn, zoomOutDown;



    /*
    you can set different proporties to different animations too:
    1s to bounce
    2s to flash
    3s to pulse
    */

    animation-delay: 2s, 5s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 2s, 5s;
}

Comment: add `.animated {
    animation-fill-mode: forwards !important;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards !important;
}` to `css`. fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nn18co76/5/

Comment: Here you can find information about animation: www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp